# Balls and bins: Probability of picking the same color given different numbers of selected balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

A bin has $n$ balls. $b$ balls are black and $w$ balls are white. I pick randomly $k$ balls, where $k$ can be $1$, $2$ or $3$ with equal probability. What is the probability that all selected balls are black?

My approach was as follows. Let $S$ define an event that all selected balls are black.
$$Pr(S) = \frac{1}{3}\left(\Pr( \text{all_black} | \text{picked 1 ball}) + 
\Pr( \text{all_black} | \text{picked 2 balls}) + 
\Pr( \text{all_black} | \text{picked 3 balls}) \right) = 
\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{b \choose 1}{n \choose 1} + \frac{b \choose 2}{n \choose 2} + \frac{b \choose 3}{n \choose 3}\right)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Yes it seems right.

Comment: Thanks both of you!

Comment: There's just a missing factor of $1/3$ after your first equality, but it appears after the second.

Comment: @DedekindCuts They're conditional probabilities the $1/3$ is implicitly in them.

Comment: @user1001001 No they do not. See the law of total probability.

Comment: @DedekindCuts Yes of course they don't! Idk why i wrote that, must've been half asleep!

Comment: @DedekindCuts Oh yes, you're right! I added it at the end, but forgot in the first equality! Thanks!